# Stacking Columns of a matrix in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I want to stack columns of a matrix in Maxima.

**Example**

```
b3: matrix(
 [1,0,0], 
 [-a21,1,0], 
 [-a31,-a32,1]
);
```

I wonder how to stack the columns of this matrix. Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an naive way of doing it:

```
c : transpose( b3 );
transpose( append( c[0], c[1], c[2] ) );
```

and here is a more general way:

```
apply(append, map(lambda([r], transpose(b3)[r]), makelist(i,i,3)));
```

Comment: Thank @soegaard for your answer. I think you mean `c : transpose( b3 );
transpose( append( c[1], c[2], c[3] ) );`. It becomes very tedious if there are many columns. I'd prefer any automated way. Anyway thanks for your answer (+1).

Comment: @MYaseen208 A more general way, which might be what you are looking for: apply(append, map(lambda([r], transpose(b3)[r]), makelist(i,i,3)));

Comment: Thanks for your help and showing interest in this problem. Your new code `apply(append, map(lambda([r], transpose(b3)[r]), makelist(i,i,3)));` produces this output `[1,-a21,-a31,0,1,-a32,0,0,1]` which is not the required output. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 Just transpose: transpose(apply(append, map(lambda([r], transpose(b3)[r]), makelist(i,i,3))));

Answer (score 2):

Or even just:

```
transpose(apply(append,args(transpose(b3))));
```